# How to sort a list of tuples but with one specific tuple being the first?

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I'm doing an application to find the best path for a delivery.

The delivery send me his path:

```py
[
    ('0', '1'),
    ('1', '2'),
    ('0', '2'),
    ('2', '0')
]
```

... where every pair of numbers is a location and smallest numbers are closer. They also send me their starting point. For example: `2`.

I did a function to sort from lower to higher:

```py
def lowToHigh(trajet):
    trajet_opti = trajet
    print(sorted(trajet_opti))
    

lowToHigh([
    ('0', '1'),
    ('1', '2'),
    ('0', '2'),
    ('2', '0')
])
```

The output is like this:

```
[('0', '1'), ('0', '2'), ('1', '2'), ('2', '0')]
```

I need a function who puts the tuple with the starting number first:

```py
def starting_tuple():
    starting_number = 2
    .
    .
    .
```

Which returns something like this:

```py
[('2', '0'), ('0', '1'), ('0', '2'), ('1', '2')]
```

Comment: What happens if your tuple list has `('2','0') and ('2','1')` ? What would you expect it to do then ? Should it choose the lower one?

Comment: Yes, exactly but  in this situation .sorted look to the second number to choose the lower. I think i dont need to worry about it

Answer (score 3):

Sort with a `key` that adds another tuple element representing whether the list item equals the starting point.

```
>>> path = [
...     ('0', '1'),
...     ('1', '2'),
...     ('0', '2'),
...     ('2', '0')
... ]
>>> sorted(path, key=lambda c: (c[0] != '2', c))
[('2', '0'), ('0', '1'), ('0', '2'), ('1', '2')]
```

The expression `c[0] != '2'` will be `False` (0) for the starting point and `True` (1) for all others, which will force the starting point to come at the start of the list.  If there are multiple starting points, they will be sorted normally relative to each other.

Comment: Thank you it's work but i have a question why did you put != in my head its not making sense

Comment: Because `False` comes before `True` in a sorted list.  If you used `==` there, the "starting number" would always be at the end of the list instead of the beginning.